# RadioButton inside ListView gives IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-listview, illegalstateexception, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I wanted to have `RadioButton` inside `ListView`, the problem is that every `RadioButton` populated in the `ListView`, has different `RadioGroup` since all of them can be selected. I want only one item to be selected and set its position's checkFlag to true and other position to false. I added each `RadioButton` using `addView` but triggered `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Here's my `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    holder = null;
    final Option optionItem = data[position];

    protected int selectedPosition = -1;
    protected boolean selectedCheckFlag = false;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                .getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new OptionHolder();

        holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) row
                .findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_survey);
        holder.radioButton = (RadioButton) row
                .findViewById(R.id.radiobutton_survey);
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (OptionHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

    holder.radioButton.setText(optionItem.option);
    holder.radioGroup.addView(holder.radioButton); // Triggered IllegalStateException

    holder.radioGroup
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                        int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RadioButton selectedRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedRadio.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    optionItem.

                    selectedCheckFlag = true;
                                selectedPosition = position;

                                if (selectedPosition > -1
                                        && selectedCheckFlag)
                                    optionItem.checkFlag = true;
                                else
                                    optionItem.checkFlag = false;
                }
            });

    return row;
}
```

Here's the item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_radio"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup_survey"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton_survey"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox_red"
        android:textColor="@color/brown" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: post your logcat details here

Comment: but you have already added RadioButton in xml then why you are trying to add same Button again ? just comment `holder.radioGroup.addView(holder.radioButton)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have already added `RadioButton` in `RadioGroup` using xml so no need to add same button again. comment `addView` line:

```
// holder.radioGroup.addView(holder.radioButton)
```

> the problem is that every RadioButton populated in the ListView, has
>   different RadioGroup since all of them can be selected. I want only
>   one item to be selected and set its position's checkFlag to true and
>   other position to false

to uncheck all radiobuttons from `RadioGroup` use call `clearCheck()` method of `RadioGroup` :

```
holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
```

Comment: If I comment that line, I can't use the `holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener` wherein I set `optionItem.checkFlag` to true. Since I have to save in the POJO `Option` for further usage.

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x : also use `holder.radioButton.getText()` instead of `RadioButton selectedRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);` to get text from selected radiobutton